# Get List Of City Names In English and Native Language

Tags: c#, api, geocoding, city

I have a web app which requires Two Drop Down Lists.
One of countries in there native language;
the language is determined by the app.
The other is for the cities in that country,
also in native language.

I have seen this on many site but couldn't find any Method. I Tried Google Revise Geo-coding but could not pass the native language:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&location_type=ROOFTOP&result_type=street_address&lang=?????
```

There is geonames.org but can't define the native language. I also tried OpenStreetMap.org but could not understand the API.

I Want the output to be like:

**Saudi Arabia -->Riad** 

**المملكة العربية السعودية--> الرياض**

If the user is English because it's the native language so the list will have both

### ***any Alternative is appreciated***

Answer (score 1):

You can't ask google geocoding api to return a location's name in native language, unless you mean native to user and not native to that location.

> By default the API will attempt to load the most appropriate language based on the **users location** or **browser settings**. Some APIs allow you to **explicitly set a language** when you make a request.

The closest you can get is probably the following, but keep it in minds this would be heavy error-prone :

- Query once with `lang=en`
- Parse the `short_name` of `types=country`
- Build yourself a lookup table that translate data from last step to the native language code of that country
- Query a second time asking for `lang={languageCode}`

Here is an list of language codes for reference : https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport

Comment: doesn't help I have like 200000 city can't translate all of them

Comment: any alternative will be appreciated

Comment: You don't have to build a language lookup table on the city level, you just need a lookup table on the country level. Again, there isn't much better alternative. And it is not that bad, *"There are 196 countries in the world today."*

Comment: there are more like 249

Comment: and i will call geocoding for every selection?